# PHP MySQL Fetch Printing Help

Tags: php, mysql, class, while-loop

Basically I have two files, group.php and class.Groups.php

I am trying to print out the 20 last messages posted to the group, however I cannot figure it out as I am pretty new to this! Any help welcomed.

The problem I am having is that the function I am calling is inside a class. Just dont know how to do the while loop and printing.

Would also welcome suggestions and feedback on my code structure & layout.

Thanks.

**class.Groups.php**

```
<?php include("config.php"); 

// Get Group Details

class Group {

 var $groupID;
 var $groupName;
 var $groupDescription;
 var $groupMessage;

 function group_details($ID) {
  $group_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE GroupID = '".$ID."' LIMIT 1");
  if (mysql_num_rows($group_details) == 1) {
   $group_details_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($group_details);
   $this->groupID = $group_details_row ['GroupID'];
   $this->groupName = $group_details_row ['Name'];
   $this->groupDescription = $group_details_row ['Description'];
  }
 }

 function group_member($ID) {
  $group_member = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GroupMembers WHERE GroupID = '".$ID."' AND UserID = '".$_SESSION['UserID']."' LIMIT 1");
  if (mysql_num_rows($group_member) == 1) {
   return 1;
  }
  else {
   return null;
  }
 }

 function group_messages($ID) {
  $group_messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GroupMessages INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserID = GroupMessages.UserID WHERE GroupID = '".$ID."' LIMIT 20");
  while ($group_messages_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($group_messages)) {
   $this->groupMessage = $group_messages_row['Message'];
  }
 }

}

?>
```

**group.php**

```
<?php include("includes/class.Groups.php");

$group = new Group;
$group->group_details($_GET['ID']);

if ($_SESSION['LoggedIn'] == 1) {
 if ($group->group_member($_GET['ID'])) {
  include("includes/header.php"); ?>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="menu"><?php include("includes/sidebar.php"); ?></div>
   <div id="main">
    <h2><?php echo $group->groupName; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $group->groupDescription; ?></p>
    <h3>Messages</h3>
    <?php 
     while ($group->group_messages($_GET['ID'])) {
      echo $group->groupMessage;
     }
    ?>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php
 }
 else {
  echo "You are not member of this group.";
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `$group->group_messages()` inside a `while`, because:

1. It doesn't return anything (return evaluates to `false`)
2. It goes through all the rows in one call, while you are expecting it to return one row at a time

You can rewrite your class code to collect all rows in a variable, return it and the iterate on it using `foreach` loop

```
// class.Groups.php
function group_messages($ID) {
  $group_messages = array();
  $group_messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM GroupMessages INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserID = GroupMessages.UserID WHERE GroupID = '".$ID."' LIMIT 20");
  while ($group_messages_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($group_messages)) {
      $group_messages[] = $group_messages_row['Message'];
  }
  return $group_messages;
}

// groups.php
<h3>Messages</h3>
<?php 
    foreach ($group->group_messages($_GET['ID']) as $group_message) {
        echo $group_message;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an extra curly brace in this chuck of code:

```
<?php 
                    while ($group->group_messages($_GET['ID'])) {
                        echo $group->groupMessage; }
                } ?>
```

Comment: } was just in the wrong place, wasn't causing a problem anyway.